# Создание базы данных в phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, joomla, база-данных

На сервере nic.ru в СУБД у меня есть база данных и пользователь, которые подключены друг к другу, а в phpmyadmin показано, что база к пользователю не подключена, решил закачать phpmyadmin в корневую папку сайта, распаковал - что дальше, как создать базу данных и пользователя; cms уже есть, подключено. Хостер - nic.ru, тариф - 201. Или подскажите, где и как можно создать базу данных и подключить при установке joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На первой странице поисковика Яндекса по запросу "phpmyadmin создание таблицы". А конкретно - эта статья: [создание таблиц в phpMyAdmin](http://phys.bspu.unibel.by/static/lib/inf/int/htmlbook/pr_213.html).

Answer (score 0):

чтоб сайт заработал мне пришлось поменять пароль в файле configuration.php 
нашёл строку
$password=fofls.f
и поменял пароль
После этого сайт появился
а также админка